# Rect elements not transitioning to data point when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, transition

```
//button event
var nextButton = d3.selectAll("#next");
nextButton.on("click", function(d, i){
    d3.selectAll("rect")
        .transition()
        .attr("duration", 2000)
        .attr("y", function(d){ return d.startDate })
});


var resetButton = d3.selectAll("#reset");
resetButton.on("click", function(d, i){
    d3.selectAll("rect")
        .transition()
        .duration(10000)
        .attr("y", 0)
});
```

When I click a button ("next") the rect elements in my chart do not move or shift to their vertical position corresponding the data on the y-axis. When I hit the "reset" button, the rect elements budge a little but then reset to the starting position. I cannot sort out how to enable the animation to take effect when "next" is clicked.

I have tried to setting a function to return "d.startDate" but I am not experienced to understand why that would not work.

an example of my chart is linked here at https://jsfiddle.net/g50c29Lp/ with the complete code. If you hit next, nothing happens, if you hit return, the elements move a little then reset as they should.

I would expect that when the next button is pushed, the elements arrange themselves vertically in correspondence to their "startDate" or why data value.

Still new to d3 and using this chart as a means of learning so I apologize if this is something that is going completely over my head.

Comment: `.attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.startDate); })` includes the scale in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `duration` is a method, not an attribute. It should be:

```
d3.selectAll("rect")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    //etc...
```

But this is not the main problem. The main problem is that, for whatever reason, you're using a **band scale** for the dates. You should treat dates as dates, and use a **time scale** instead.

So, since you are using a band scale (which, again, I recommend you replace), do not parse the strings, removing all this:

```
const parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.startDate = parse(d.startDate);
  d.endDate = parse(d.endDate);
});
```

Also, do not forget to use the scale for the `y` position.

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 50, right: 150, bottom: 50, left: 0},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 350 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#main-chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + 100 + "," + 20 + ")");

//declaring other variables
var barPadding = 1;

// append the data
d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GideonBelete/employment/master/employment.json', function(data) { 

// X axis
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ 0, width ])
  .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Name; }))
  .padding(0.2);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
  .selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
    .style("text-anchor", "end");

// Y axis
var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([ 0, height ])
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.startDate; }))
    .padding(.1);
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(0)")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

// create the squares
    svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (width / data.length - barPadding);
    })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 15)
    .attr("height", 15)

// mouse events
    .on("mouseover", function() {
        tooltip.style("display", null);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        tooltip.style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
        var xPos = d3.mouse(this)[0] - 15;
        var yPos = d3.mouse(this)[1] - 55;
        tooltip.attr("tranform", "translate(" + xPos + "," + yPos + ")");
        tooltip.select("text").text(d.Name + " - " + d.Position);
    })

//button event
    var nextButton = d3.selectAll("#next");
    nextButton.on("click", function(d, i){
        d3.selectAll("rect")
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.startDate) })
    });
    

    var resetButton = d3.selectAll("#reset");
    resetButton.on("click", function(d, i){
        d3.selectAll("rect")
            .transition()
            .duration(2000)
            .attr("y", 0)
    });

// tooltip text
    var tooltip = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("display", "none");
    
    tooltip.append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("dy", -10)
        .style("font-size", "12px")
        .style("font-weight", "light");

// color for past/present employees
    d3.selectAll("rect")
        .each(function(d, i) {
            if (i === 1) {
                d3.select(this)
                .style("fill", "#C2C5CC")
            }
        })
        .each(function(d, i) {
            if (i === 2) {
                d3.select(this)
                .style("fill", "#C2C5CC")
            }
        })
        .each(function(d, i) {
            if (i === 3) {
                d3.select(this)
                .style("fill", "#C2C5CC")
            }
        })
        .each(function(d, i) {
            if (i === 5) {
                d3.select(this)
                .style("fill", "#C2C5CC")
            }
        })
        .each(function(d, i) {
            if (i === 7) {
                d3.select(this)
                .style("fill", "#C2C5CC")
            }
        })
        .each(function(d, i) {
            if (i === 9) {
                d3.select(this)
                .style("fill", "#C2C5CC")
            }
        })
        .each(function(d, i) {
            if (i === 10) {
                d3.select(this)
                .style("fill", "#C2C5CC")
            }
        })
        .each(function(d, i) {
            if (i === 11) {
                d3.select(this)
                .style("fill", "#C2C5CC")
            }
        });
});
```

```css
.title {
  margin-top: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  cursor: default;
}

.title h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.title h4 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.divider {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

rect {
  fill: #49A99D;
}

svg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.information {
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 70%;
}

.button {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#next {
  background: #49A99D;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

#next:active {
  background: #C2C5CC;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

#reset {
  background: #49A99D;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

#reset:active {
  background: #C2C5CC;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.information h4 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: default;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main-chart"></div>
  <div class="information">
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and clarification. I will read further into the different types of scales and methods!